# Installed Zend Framework 2.x skeleton program in XAMPP, what's next?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, xampp

I've just successfully installed the zend framework using XAMPP. The skeleton application works well. What I'm missing is which is the main file I can edit now for future programming?

Is it `c:\xampp\apps\myapp\htdocs\public\index.php`?
I noticed that when I edit it the homepage actually changes but I'm not 100% sure that it's the right file.

Thanks for the answers!

Cheers

Comment: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/user-guide/overview.html

Answer (score 1):

Zend Framework 2 is an MVC framework, it means that models (the objects you will manipulate), the views (the pages that will be displayed) and the controllers (the logic and the links beetwen models and views) are separated. So you will have to edit several files for each actions, plus the glue and the configuration files.

If you don't know what to edit and are not sure of what you do, I strongly suggest you to read and follow the tutorial, wich will help you to learn Zend Framework 2, developping a small application: https://framework.zend.com/manual/2.4/en/user-guide/overview.html

`c:\xampp\apps\myapp\htdocs\public\index.php` is the file wich will iniialize and start the framework. You should not modify it.